# sort object based on attribute

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have a txt file, each row contains a name and age (name always unique but age can be same).

Could anyone suggest a good algorithm to print out names while their ages are in ascending/descending order? (names of people having same age don't need to keep the order in the txt)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us an example of your file and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the problem reading in the file or sorting a list of tuples by the second element of said tuples?

Comment: If you provide some attempt you it would help your chances if getting a good answer

Comment: Thanks, the problem is sorting. Say we have (a, 10), (b, 5), (c, 11). Need an algorithm to sort it to (c, 11), (a, 10), (b,5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks, the problem is sorting. Say we have (a, 10), (b, 5), (c, 11). Need an algorithm to sort it to (c, 11), (a, 10), (b,5)

Alright, I assume you have these tuples in a list. You can use the built-in `sorted` function and give it a key function which specifies the property by which the elements of your list are sorted.

```
>>> people = [('bob', 28), ('alice', 21), ('jeff', 78)]
>>> sorted(people, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
[('jeff', 78), ('bob', 28), ('alice', 21)]
```

Here `lambda tup: tup[1]` will return the second element of each tuple. This is the value by which the tuples will be sorted. `reverse=True` is set to sort the tuples in descending order.

Comment: Use operator.itemgetter or operator.attrgetter instead of lambda. (attrgetter if it's a namedtuple). It's more idiomatic and also faster.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh why would I need an import for such a trivial task?

Comment: Because that's kinda the point of the builtin library. Sure, you can write a lambda, but itemgetter is specific, it's useful, and also ~50% faster.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Point taken.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh If you want to put this in an answer, I will retract mine. I was busy answering, so I missed that you already adressed this issue in your comment.

Comment: @AlexVorndran, I liked your answer. No worries.

Comment: @timgeb: Adding to Alexander's argument, `itemgetter` does one thing, and if I see it, I know what it's doing and can't get fooled. Mistaking `lambda x: (x[1], -x[0], x[4])` for `lambda x: (x[1], x[0], x[4])` is really easy to do though, so for future maintainers, I'd use `itemgetter(1, 0, 4)` for the latter; only use `lambda` to say "I'm doing something sufficiently unique and non-obvious that the standard lib doesn't support it so pay attention".

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426649/5682996) given by timegeb would be to use an `itemgetter` from the `operator` package ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)).

```
from operator import itemgetter
people = [('bob', 28), ('alice', 21), ('jeff', 78)]
print(sorted(people, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Which will give you the exact same result

```
[('jeff', 78), ('bob', 28), ('alice', 21)]
```

`itemgetter` acts as replacement for the `lambda` expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the names/ages in a dictionary with something like (will depend on your actual file format - the following assumes a name followed by age on each line, separated by whitespace):

```
names = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, age = line.split()
    names[name] = int(age)
```

Then it is easy to sort - to sort by the name (not what you suggested, but just FYI), use:

```
sorted(names)
```

To sort by ages, change the key used to do the sort:

```
sorted(names, key=lambda i: names[i])
```

So, to print, you might use:

```
for name in sorted(names, key=lambda i: names[i]):
    print(name, names[name])
```